# doxygen: How to create ".uml" file from source code of c++ using doxygen?

Tags: uml, doxygen, graphviz, class-diagram

I have used doxygen, no dobt very good tool. 
I used Doxygen + Graphviz, to generate uml like diagrams from it, but those are image files shown on webpage.

> And my requirement is specific to ***.uml*** files.

So Is there any way to generate ***.uml*** files from c++ source code.

Comment: Can you explain what a .uml file is, is it a file read by a specific program?

Comment: What I really need is UML format any of these extensions (uml, umlj, mdj, umlf, mfj). For example StarUML creates .mdj file

Comment: StarUML can read .uml files